# Creating a plugin for CEF3 in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, awesomium, ogre3d, chromium-embedded

I was able to find a basic implementation of CEF3 in Ogre3D -- but I was hoping there would be something similar for Unity3D.

[Link](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=79079)

I am currently using Awesomium, however, I now need to use RTCPeerConnection (which requires Chromium 29+).  Currently, Awesomium is only on Chromium 18, and its unclear how long it will take for that to be udpated (not going to hold my breath).

CEF is open source and updated very frequently.

I would do this myself, but I have no clue where to start. I am hoping:

1. Someone with enough Unity experience has either already created a CEF3 wrapper that they would be willing to share with the community, or
2. Someone knows how this could be accomplished and can (hopefully thoroughly) explain

Answer (score 0):

i took a look at your link and the video and i think i have some useful resources to share.

i have a bit of experience on unity3d. i've never tried to embed webpages within it, HOWEVER i've stumbled accross and read a few conversations on the subject in my travels.

**[there is one discussion here on the unity site, that i think would interest you](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/266962/how-to-display-web-page-inside-unity-.html)**

## UnityWebCore plugin

Also on the unity boards - someone has gone ahead and done some of the paving the way, **[provided a project with some demos and downloadable source here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/83071-Unity3d-plugin-for-embedding-webpages-on-WINDOWS-is-ready!)**.

its not exactly Chromium Embedded Frames, but from best i can tell from your link this will accomplish what you need. (or at least get you started)

EDIT:

another discussion specifically relating to **[doing this with awesomium here](http://labs.awesomium.com/unity3d-integration-tutorial-part-1/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me.  I specifically need to make use of RTCPeerConnection, which is a relatively bleeding edge technology found in Chromium 29+... :/

Comment: then as far as i can tell on the unity boards - this has not yet been done using that specific tech you require. maybe worth checking github and the like - some of those projects don't get all the "seo" benefits or exposure